# FTP Mock for .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, ftp, mocking

Is there a mock implementation for a ftp server that I can use in my UnitTests. I don't want my tests to depend on a real FTP server.

For JAVA a ftpmock can be found [here](http://mockftpserver.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: did you find an ftpmock to use in .net? as i couldn't get it from @Ian Davis answer below.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303640/unit-integration-testing-ftp-access/6580866#6580866

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Indy Sockets project? They have mocks/stubs for testing their client/servers: http://www.indyproject.org/SocketsCLR/index.EN.aspx - There is another version being worked on, but it hasn't been committed to since March of 2008.

Comment: It looks like that project does not exist anymore.